# __activemask() vs __ballot_sync()

Tags: cuda, gpu-warp

After read [this](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/) post on CUDA Developer Blog I am struggling to understand when is safe\correct use `__activemask()` in place of `__ballot_sync()`.

In section **Active Mask Query**, the authors wrote:

> This is incorrect, as it would result in partial sums instead of a
>   total sum.

and after, in section **Opportunistic Warp-level Programming** they are using the function `__activemask()` because:

> This may be difficult if you want to use warp-level programming inside
>   a library function but you cannot change the function interface.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no `__active_mask()` in CUDA.  That is  a typo (in [the blog article](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/)).  It should be `__activemask()`.

`__activemask()` is [only a query](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions).  It asks the question "which threads in the warp are currently executing this instruction, in this cycle?"  which is equivalent to asking "which threads in the warp are currently converged at this point?"

It has no effect on convergence. It will not cause threads to converge.  It has no warp synchronizing behavior.

`__ballot_sync()` on the other hand has converging behavior (according to the supplied `mask`).

The primary differentiation here should be considered in light of the Volta warp execution model.  Volta and beyond, because of hardware changes in the warp execution engine, can support threads in a warp being diverged in a larger number of scenarios, and for a longer time, than can previous architectures.

The divergence we are referring to here is incidental divergence due to previous conditional execution.  Enforced divergence due to explicit coding is identical before or after Volta.

Let's consider an example:

```
if (threadIdx.x < 1){
   statement_A();}
statement_B();
```

Assuming the threadblock X dimension is greater than 1, `statement_A()` is in an area of *enforced* divergence.  The warp will be in a diverged state when `statement_A()` is executed.

What about `statement_B()` ?  The CUDA execution model makes no particular statements about whether the warp will be in a diverged state or not when `statement_B()` is executed (see note 1 below).  In a pre-Volta execution environment, programmers would typically expect that there is some sort of warp reconvergence at the closing curly-brace of the previous `if` statement (although CUDA makes no guarantees of that).  Therefore the general expectation is that `statement_B()` would be executed in a non-diverged state.

However in the Volta execution model, not only are there no guarantees provided by CUDA, but in practice we may observe the warp to be in a diverged state at `statement_B()`.  *Divergence* at `statement_B()` isn't required for code correctness (whereas it is required at `statement_A()`), nor is *convergence* at `statement_B()` required by the CUDA execution model.  If there is divergence at `statement_B()` as may occur in the Volta execution model, I'm referring to this as *incidental* divergence.  It is divergence that arises not out of some requirement of the code, but typically as a result of some kind of previous conditional execution behavior.

If we have no divergence at `statement_B()`, then these two expressions (if they were at `statement_B()`) should return the same result:

```
int mask = __activemask();
```

and

```
int mask = __ballot_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, 1);
```

So in the pre-volta case, when we would typically not expect divergence at `statement_B()` in practice these two expressions return the same value.

In the Volta execution model, we can have *incidental* divergence at  `statement_B()`.  Therefore these two expressions might not return the same result.  Why?

The `__ballot_sync()` instruction, like all other CUDA 9+ warp level intrinsics which have a mask parameter, have a *synchronizing* effect.  If we have code-enforced divergence, if the synchronizing "request" indicated by the mask argument cannot be fulfilled (as would be the case above where we are requesting full convergence), that would represent illegal code.

However if we have *incidental* divergence (only, for this example), the `__ballot_sync()` semantics are to first *reconverge the warp at least to the extent that the mask argument is requesting*, then perform the requested ballot operation.

The `__activemask()` operation has no such reconvergence behavior.  It simply reports the threads that are currently converged.  If some threads are diverged, for *whatever reason*, they will not be reported in the return value.

If you then created code that performed some warp level operation (such as a warp-level sum-reduction as suggested in the blog article) and selected the threads to participate based on `__activemask()` vs. `__ballot_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, 1)`, you could conceivably get a different result, in the presence of *incidental* divergence.  The `__activemask()` realization, in the presence of *incidental* divergence, would compute a result that did not include all threads (i.e. it would compute a "partial" sum).  On the other hand, the `__ballot_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, 1)` realization, because it would first eliminate the incidental divergence, would force all threads to participate (computing a "total" sum).

A similar example and description as what I have given here is given around listing 10 in the blog article.

An example of where it could be correct to use `__activemask` is given in the blog article on "opportunistic warp-level programming", here:

```
int mask = __match_all_sync(__activemask(), ptr, &pred);
```

this statement is saying "tell me which threads are converged" (i.e. the `__activemask()` request), and then "use (at least) those threads to perform the `__match_all` operation.  This is perfectly legal and will use whatever threads happen to be converged at that point.  As that listing 9 example continues, the `mask` computed in the above step is used in the only other warp-cooperative primitive:

```
res = __shfl_sync(mask, res, leader);
```

(which happens to be right after a piece of conditional code).  This determines which threads are available, and then forces the use of those threads, regardless of what incidental divergence may have existed, to produce a predictable result.

As an additional clarification on the usage of the `mask` parameter, note the [usage statements in the PTX guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions-shfl-sync).  In particular, the `mask` parameter is not intended to be an exclusion method.  If you wish threads to be excluded from the shuffle operation, you must use conditional code to do that.  This is important in light of the following statement from the PTX guide:

> The behavior of shfl.sync is undefined if the executing thread is not in the membermask.

Furthermore, although not directly related to the above discussion, there is an "exception" to the forced divergence idea for `__shfl_sync()`.  The [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#independent-thread-scheduling-7-x) states that this is acceptable on volta and beyond:

```
if (tid % warpSize < 16) {
    ...
    float swapped = __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, val, 16);
    ...
} else {
    ...
    float swapped = __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, val, 16);
    ...
}
```

The reason for this is hinted at there, and we can get a further explanation of behavior in this case from the [PTX guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions-shfl-sync):

> shfl.sync will cause executing thread to wait until all non-exited threads corresponding to membermask have executed shfl.sync with the same qualifiers and same membermask value before resuming execution.

This means that the `__shfl_sync()` in the `if`-path and the `__shfl_sync()` in the `else`-path are effectively working together in this case to produce a defined result for all threads in the warp.    A few caveats:

- This statement applies to cc7.0 and higer
- Other constructs are not necessarily going to work.  For example this:

  ```
    if (tid % warpSize < 16) {
        ...
        float swapped = __shfl_xor_sync(0xffffffff, val, 16);
        ...
    } else {
    }
  ```

will not provide interesting results for any thread in the warp.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71152284/cuda-independent-thread-scheduling) question/answer may also be of interest.

(note 1) This is perhaps a non-intuitive concept.  The CUDA programming model allows for incidental divergence to occur or appear at any point in device code, for no reason at all.  The [blog article](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/) makes reference to this concept in several places, I will excerpt one here:

> It assumes that threads in the same warp that are once synchronized will stay synchronized until the next thread-divergent branch. Although it is often true, it is not guaranteed in the CUDA programming model.